# Delay load Javascript in HTML page with GWT

Tags: javascript, gwt

We have a GWT app that displays ads on the page with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="app/app.nocache.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="top-ads-placeholder" class="uk-hidden-small uk-hidden">
            <div id="top-ads-small" class="uk-hidden-small">
                <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ads.qadservice.com/t?id=123'></script>
            </div>
            <div id="top-ads-large" class="uk-hidden-medium uk-hidden-large uk-container-center uk-width-1-1">
                <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ads.qadservice.com/t?id=123'></script>
            </div>
        </div>
</body
```

The problem with this code is its a blocking and it delays the loading of the app. What we want is to make sure that the GWT app has fully loaded (especially its UI) before the ads script will even load. Is that possible?

Comment: load this js inside the onModule by adding timer delay..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this block to the page at the end of your `onModuleLoad()` or whenever you think your app is ready.